# In XSLT, Replace one class value when there are multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working with an XSL transformation that's being applied to an HTML document. Relevant HTML example:

```
<div class="row home-row">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

I select items that match this with the following XSL (which is working nicely):

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' row ')]" priority="1">
```

Then, if a condition I've earlier checked matches, I replace "row" with "row-fluid" like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="original-row-class" select="string(@class)" />
<xsl:variable name="row-class">
                  <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$original-row-class" />    
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="' row '" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="' row-fluid '" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$row-class" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'class']|node()[local-name() != 'class']"/>
                </xsl:copy>
```

This also works fairly well, except that it replaces all mentions of "row" with "row-fluid" even if they are inside "home-row". What I'd like to do is change the "row" classes to "row-fluid", but ignore the "home-row" classes while doing so. Is this possible?

I should mention that I am locked into XSLT 1.0.

**Update**: adding the replace template below (should've thought of that earlier!):

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Can you should us the "replace" template you are calling, as the issue is actually within the code for that. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, I should've thought that might be the case. Updated.

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure you are showing the correct XSLT though? It's just that when you call the "replace" template, you are passing it ' row ' as parameter, with spaces either side, but you are also passing it the original class name, without the space at the start. This means the "replace" template should not actually replace anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a few touches to your original transformation and it now works in the wanted way -- no extension functions are needed:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row ')]">
   <xsl:variable name="original-row-class" select="string(@class)" />
   <xsl:variable name="row-class">
     <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select=
        "concat(' ', $original-row-class, ' ')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="' row '" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="' row-fluid '" />
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($row-class)" />
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "@*[local-name() != 'class']|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="by" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
              <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
              <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div class="row home-row">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div class="row-fluid home-row">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Just what I was looking for. Many thanks, Dimitre.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to split the class string into words with an recurcive template call.
[e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953621/). And compare / replase each word.

OK and here is a solution based on the recursive approach.

```
        <xsl:template match="test" >
            <xsl:variable name ="new_class">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace_words">
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'xx'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'yyy'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="words" select="'xx xx-a xx-b xx xx'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$new_class"/>

        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="replace_words">
            <xsl:param name="replace"/>
            <xsl:param name="by"/>
            <xsl:param name="words"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($words,' ')">
                    <!-- try replace first word-->
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace_words">
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="words" select="substring-before($words,' ')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <!-- dlimeter -->
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace_words">
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="words" select="substring-after($words,' ')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$replace = $words">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$words"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does seem compelling, but I'm failing to get it implemented correctly. It seems to just remove both.

Comment: @Jonathan Stegall glad I could help. Even if it was only a hint for the right direction.

Comment: Tokenization isn't necessary at all for solving this problem. There exists a more straight-forward and much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what seems to have worked for me. Skipping the separating lines and pasting all of it below.

While I got this working right before the below answer was posted, I did try that one and it didn't immediately work. I think at this point I'd be curious if there's something terribly wrong with this, but otherwise I'll stick with it. Fantastic direction-giving below, at the very least.

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' row ')]" priority="1">

    <xsl:param name="separator" select="' '" />

    <xsl:variable name="class-array">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="$original-row-class"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$original-row-class" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="ext:node-set($class-array)" />

    <xsl:variable name="row-class">
        <xsl:for-each select="$items/item">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". = 'row'">row-fluid</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". = 'row'"><xsl:value-of select="concat($separator, 'row-fluid') "/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat($separator, .) "/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$row-class" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="original-row-class" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'class']|node()[local-name() != 'class']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $sep))">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $sep))"/>
            </item>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Actually, your original transformation needed just a few touches to make it work in the wanted way -- no tokenization and no extension functions are needed.